# PowerShell Script Stop-Restart Service on Windows Server 2022 via Intranet App - Not Working

Tags: powershell

I've got an aspx intranet app written in VB, that calls a PowerShell script to stop and restart a service. It is run using an ID in the local admin group and works fine on all servers but is not working on Windows 2022 Server. It'll return errors such as the following: Cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open 'myService' service on computer 'Win2022 Server'.

The script lives locally on the servers root, and has permissions granted to all local admins. The PS versions are all v5+. The app and script function properly on all other servers except Windows 2022 Server. I've been struggling with this if anyone can provide some guidance or help whatsoever.
thanks

When the PS script is run locally on the server right from PwerShell ISE, not invoked from intranet application, it runs fine. When run remotely either from Intranet app in Edge, or from File Explorer, the PS's Stop-Service fails with the error above.
This is the PowerShell script:

```
$running = "Running" 
$stopPending = "StopPending"
$stopped = "Stopped"
$serviceDNm = "Video Service"
$serviceSrvcNm = "VideoService"
$srvrname = "Win2022Server"

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 

$s = (Get-Service -Name $serviceSrvcNm -Computername $srvrname)

Get-Service -Name $serviceSrvcNm -ComputerName $srvrname | Set-Service -Status stopped

s.Stop() 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

$s = (Get-Service -Computername $srvrname -Name $serviceSrvcNm) 
if($s.status -eq "Stopped")
        {
           $s.Start() #start-service -name $s.Name -PassThru
        }
```

Comment: Did you start powershell by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Yes, I've tested that. The script runs properly when runas admin. But the app calling the script also uses an admin id (in servers local admin group) as well. This works on all other servers but not the newer Windows Server 2022 OS.

Comment: There should be no difference on Windows Server 2022.  The machines must be configured differently.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts?force_isolation=true#administrator-account  The top of page says Applies to:
✅ Windows 10, ✅ Windows 11, ✅ Windows Server 2016, ✅ Windows Server 2019, ✅ Windows Server 2022

Comment: I've been through every inch of the Win 2022 server's config, comparing it to all other Server OSs this application stops and starts services on, and all the servers are config'd literally identical. Especially the security authorizations and access.

Comment: It may be a Group Policy which is not on the machine.

Comment: That's a good point jdweng...let me look into that. 
Thanks and I'll keep this thread updated.

Comment: Group Policy isn't the issue, as all other servers can have services stopped and restarted using same credentials. Its just the Windows Server 2022 that are not.

Comment: Are they in a different domain?  Check DNS suffix and search list from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL

Comment: All servers live on the same domain. 
PowerShell script called by a VB Intranet app (aspx page)

Comment: Did you compare the IPConfig between working and non working machines?

Comment: IPConfig /all of them...all on same domain. 
All of these servers, other than operating systems, 
are made from the same image.

Comment: Can you ping them?  Maybe just an IP routing issue.

Comment: The application pings the server first. If the ping replies, then the powershell scipt is called to perform the service restart. It's here where it fails on all Windows 2022 servers. Same credentials are passed to all servers, made from same image. Other than OS, all servers are config'd identically.

Comment: Maybe you have duplicate IPs.  Disconnect machine from ethernet and then try ping.  If it responds you are connected to wrong machine.

Comment: All IP addresses are unique. They have to be.

Comment: Only if they are in the same subnet do they have to be unique.  I've seen too many cases of duplicate IPs.  Always best when having issues is to remove ethernet a ping by both computer name and IP.

Comment: Agree. Some servers are same subnets, some are on others, 
but all with unique IPs.

Comment: It not just a single Windows 2022 server having this issue. 
It's ALL of our Win2022 Servers that are not allowing local admin IDs from executing the PowerShell's Stop service command. 
All older Windows OSs operating fine.

Comment: Also being that the script is called by an aspx page, I made sure the IIS was running the proper app pool: .NET 4.5 Integrated.

Comment: I do not know your network nor domains.  Only what you posted.  I know it is happening on my the one machine.  So I'm looking for something common that is not just on the machine but the network configuration as well. I usually like using File Explorer and verify that I have access to files and folder on remote machines to make sure you can connect.  You should be able to see files in remote machines using \\servername.

Comment: Good test there, JDWeng. I've been using UNC paths in file explorer to confirm the scripts path, existence and access: \\servername\scriptsfolder\scriptname.ps1 and can access it no problem on all servers, regardless of OS. 
But I'm in the admin group. So my access is really unrestricted.

Comment: The actual event is a Failure Audit, attempting to use a System32 file, (C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe) to stop and restart the target service. The id used has admin rights to Windows\Sys32 folder, but it seems not svchost.exe. The access on this Win2022 Server is identical to all earlier OSs, that CAN access Windows\Sys32svchost.exe and stop the targeted service.

Comment: Is error coming from Event Viewer or Powershell?  Is version of svchost.exe same on working and non working?  svchost.exe says it using RSA Sha256 on my win 10 machine in details.  Maybe the encryption method is different.  The version powershell could be different in System32\WindowsPowerShell

Comment: Maybe trusted root certificates are not compatible : http://woshub.com/updating-trusted-root-certificates-in-windows-10/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Great questions...let me look into these. I'll keep you posted.
Thanks JDWeng

Comment: I'm retrieving errors from Event Viewer. The svchost.exe versions are of course upgraded for Win2022 Server (v10.0.2) whereas the older server OSs are 10.0.1. Both using RSO Sha256. No encryption method differences. Same with Powershell.exe: 10.0.2 for Win2022 and 10.0.1 for other server OSs. I've added .NET 4.5 Application pool to Win2022 server's IIS, and now error is Event 4673 - Failure Audit with C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
!!!

Comment: Is issue that you are using Powershell 1.0 which probably won't work with RSO Sha 256?  Window 2022 is probably using SHA 386 : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel?force_isolation=true

Comment: Do you mean SHA 384 ?

Comment: Yes.   Small typo.

Comment: Win Server 2022 servers use PowerShell.exe & ISE v10.0.2, 
which throws an access error, of aspx calling the PowerShell script.
The older Win servers use 10.0.1, which work fine.

Comment: Yes, but the 2022 may require different SHA method.  So you do not know if it is powershell or a configuration issue.  See : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/2019-sha-2-code-signing-support-requirement-for-windows-and-wsus-64d1c82d-31ee-c273-3930-69a4cde8e64f